# How to work with posts and sub posts?

Tags: posts, advanced-custom-fields

I am working on a site for a film-festival-archive. I need some kind of a post and sub-post structure.
Like:

2018 Main festival post

-- directors

-- locations

-- press material

Each sub post has its own page. An all of the sub posts should be handled flexibly, so for example for another year the structure will like:

2019 Main festival post

-- about the festival

-- directors

-- another info

At the moment I am working with an ACF Repeater Field and one post for each year.

The repeater is called "sub posts". And i can add as much sub posts as I need to a festival-post.
This is all great but at the end it is hard to maintain the post because its include all the sub-posts. So its a lot of information in one post.

Is there any other possibility to achieves this?

How can I split the content into different posts and still have a flexible system?

is this only possible by using wordpress pages?

Comment: Getting opinions or options on content management strategy is not really on-topic for this site. Ideally questions are development related questions that have definitive answers. If you have a more manageable approach in mind you could ask about implementing that.

Comment: You should definetly look into Custom Post Types. It is perfect for your purpose. Instead of using ACF, creating a custom post type is the way to go in my opinion. This tutorial even assumes a movie example like in your case. https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/ It's all over the web.

Comment: "is this only possible by using WordPress pages?" - no, you could create a custom post type with the parent-child relationship support, and for certain data like directors and locations, you might want to create them as custom taxonomies and assign them to the custom post type. That way, the structure would be more organized.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at hierachical cpts!